# AWS Lambda: Get Latest Modified n number of Files from a s3 bucket folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We need to get the latest 4 files which are uploaded into s3 bucket folder.
But it was not returning the exact result.
Below my code

```
 let params = { Bucket: bucket };
 let keys = [];
 const response = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
            response.Contents.forEach(item => {
                if (item.Key !== prefix) {
                    keys.push(item.Key);
                }
            });
```

Then sort the keys and get 0 to 3 files.
any good way to get this?

Comment: At no point is it checking when the file was modified. Are you determining the "latest modified" file in some other way?

Comment: yes I canot find any way to get sort by lastmodified in s3 bucket folder

Comment: The objects in the `Contents` array have a `LastModified` property. So you should be able to just sort by that.

Comment: "But it was not returning the exact result." - what does it mean? What was it returning and what was expected outcome?

Comment: Objects are returned in alphabetical (well, UTF-8) order. They are _not_ returned in date order.